# Generating new random number onclick

Tags: c#

Everytime I click the button that is supposed to generate a new random number, the number just stays the same. How can I have the same variable, but new number onclick?

```
static Random random = new Random();
static int randomNumber1 = random.Next(0, 100);
static int randomNumber2 = random.Next(0, 100);
num1Label.Text = randomNumber1.ToString();
num2Label.Text = randomNumber2.ToString();

protected void submitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    answerStatus.Visible = true;

    int counter = 0;
    int answer = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;
    if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text == answer.ToString())
    {
        answerStatus.Text = "Correct!";
        randomNumber1 = random.Next(2, 22);
        randomNumber2 = random.Next(2, 222);
        num1Label.Visible = true;
        num2Label.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: debuggers are great! You have one. Please try using it.

Comment: You update the numbers on a click but not the label text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected void submitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        answerStatus.Visible = true;

        int counter = 0;
        int answer = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;
        if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text == answer.ToString())
        {
            answerStatus.Text = "Correct!";
            randomNumber1 = random.Next(2, 22);
            randomNumber2 = random.Next(2, 222);
             num1Label.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber1);//add this line 
             num2Label.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber2); //and this line
            num1Label.Visible = true;
            num2Label.Visible = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
randomNumber1 = random.Next(2, 22);
randomNumber2 = random.Next(2, 222);
num1Label.Visible = true;
num2Label.Visible = true;
```

I see nowhere where you're actually *putting* those two new random numbers into a control of some sort. You're making the controls *visible* but that doesn't magically populate them with new values.

Without setting the values, you're generating new numbers but the user isn't ever seeing them.

You'll need to change the textual property of the `num1Label` control to be the string value of `randomNumber1`. Ditto for the second control and number.

Comment: num1Label.Text = randomNumber1.ToString();
num2Label.Text = randomNumber2.ToString();  The label is assigned to the random number at the top of my posted code

Comment: @user3880824, that happens _once_ at the start, not every time through the click function as required.